# How to change the URL for Web UI Foreman?

Tags: puppet, apache2, foreman, puppet-foreman

Hi Can I change the url link for the web UI interface? I am using Foreman 3.9 versions. I try to change url with foreman-installer --foreman-url but I get error with ssl-certificate problem. Changing config /etc/foreman/settings.yml and /etc/foreman-proxy/settings.yml doesn’t work.